# Offline only app for smartphones in Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, cordova

Can I write a offline only application using HTML, CSS and Javascript ( + AngularJS) for mobile devices (for example with cordova), so the user won't need any internet connection to start and use the application. As far as I know cordova just creates a webview and I wonder now, how will the page be shown, when there is no hosting...

Imagine a simple calculator or todo app which works just offline.
Is this possible? Or do I have other ways except cordova...

Comment: it's possible, all the web code is written and packaged in the app. It's all directly on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pages are hosted inside the app. The html,js,css files are packed inside the apk. When a user install the app it download the pages within the app. And webview access the pages locally. So you can make app both online and offline.

suppose the android project directory. Html pages are kept in the directory

```
yourprojectfolder\android\assets\www
```

And in the java file at the app start it just create the webview and call the index.html page. Now if you need any device function like notification / geolocation you can use them using plugin. Plugins are those that creates bridge between html and java files.

Also several databases are available for phonegap development. So you can store data locally. Go through the documentation for more and create & understand the structure.